# Decryption of string returning empty

Tags: c#, php, encryption, openssl

I am working with trying to decrypt a string using `openssl_decrypt`. For some reason or another no matter what I have tried, this always returns empty. Here is a little function I am working with; **not production code**.

**PHP Code**

```
public function Decrypt($string)
    {
        $password = "somepassword";
        $method = "aes-256-cbc";
        $hashPassword = hash('sha256', $password);
        $iv = chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0);

        return openssl_decrypt(base64_decode($string), $method, $hashPassword, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);

    }
```

On another note, the encryption happens on `c#` side, using `Xamarin` to make web calls. Below is the encrypt function I am using currently.

**C# Code**

```
 private static readonly byte[] FIELDS_KEY = SHA256.Create().ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("PASSWORDHERE"));
 private static readonly byte[] FIELDS_IV = new byte[16] { 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0 };


public static string EncryptString(string plainText)
        {
            // Instantiate a new Aes object to perform string symmetric encryption
            Aes encryptor = Aes.Create();

            encryptor.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

            // Set key and IV
            byte[] aesKey = new byte[32];
            Array.Copy(FIELDS_KEY, 0, aesKey, 0, 32);
            encryptor.Key = aesKey;
            encryptor.IV = FIELDS_IV;

            // Instantiate a new MemoryStream object to contain the encrypted bytes
            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

            // Instantiate a new encryptor from our Aes object
            ICryptoTransform aesEncryptor = encryptor.CreateEncryptor();

            // Instantiate a new CryptoStream object to process the data and write it to the 
            // memory stream
            CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, aesEncryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);

            // Convert the plainText string into a byte array
            byte[] plainBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(plainText);

            // Encrypt the input plaintext string
            cryptoStream.Write(plainBytes, 0, plainBytes.Length);

            // Complete the encryption process
            cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();

            // Convert the encrypted data from a MemoryStream to a byte array
            byte[] cipherBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();

            // Close both the MemoryStream and the CryptoStream
            memoryStream.Close();
            cryptoStream.Close();

            // Convert the encrypted byte array to a base64 encoded string
            string cipherText = Convert.ToBase64String(cipherBytes, 0, cipherBytes.Length);

            // Return the encrypted data as a string
            return cipherText;
        }
```

I am really not sure what I am missing here to be honest, when I check the password coming in, checked the hashed password and IV all seem to checkout from the encrypt side of the `c#` function.

Comment: Hm... why are you using a hashed password to decrypt? Encryption didn't use a hashed password, did it?

Comment: @LarsStegelitz it is hashed actually, that is how the `key` is set from `FIELDS_KEY `... I left out the two fields on accident in the `c#` code.

Comment: Well.. then what about the different Passwords? C# "PASSWORDHERE", PHP "somepassword"...

Comment: @LarsStegelitz Those are the same on my end, that is just for posting on a public site and *are not real*.

Comment: In the current PHP-code, the [`hash`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php)-method returns the result as a hexadecimal string. Since [`openssl_decrypt`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-decrypt.php) expects binary data, this string has to be converted with `hex2bin` afterwards. Alternatively, the third parameter `$raw_output` in the `hash`-method can be set to `TRUE`, so that the result is returned _directly_ as binary data.

Comment: @Topaco thanks for the suggestions, I tried them, unfortunately they didn't work. The output is still an empty string.

Comment: Dream code... you show different code than what you actually have - chances are, that the "dream code" doesn't even have the specific problem you're asking for (had this in other forums). Please always post real code - copy & paste. 
Suggestion: Build encrypt and decrypt in BOTH languages. Once you can successfully do both in both languages, mix them (encrypt here, decrypt there). Maybe your C# code is faulty already? There are also websites where you can encrypt/decrypt - use these to verify the output of your routines..

Comment: @LarsStegelitz The only difference is the arg names because that is where the actual password goes; it's all *real* code and I can successfully encrypt and decrypt in c#. The issue I am facing is the `openssl` decrypt in `php`, no errors, just nothing is returned. Also, I did try a few to *test* the encryption and decryption and surprisingly they work.

Comment: Can't reproduce the issue. The code `https://pastebin.com/JFCHqtLi` runs e.g. on `https://repl.it/languages/php_cli`

Comment: Holy smokes @Topaco that works! `$hashPassword = hash('sha256', $password, $raw_output = true);` the `$raw_output=true` did it; I just had `true` there! Thank you so much, if you create an answer I'll be glad to accept it, thanks again!

Comment: Remember @Topaco, comments may disappear but answers are forever. We like answers here, hint, hint ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`hash`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php)-method returns the result as a hexadecimal string in the current PHP-code. However, the [`openssl_decrypt`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-decrypt.php)-method requires the key as binary data, so that a conversion e.g. with [`hex2bin`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hex2bin.php) is necessary:

```
$hashPassword = hex2bin(hash('sha256', $password));
```

Alternatively, the 3rd parameter (`raw_output`) of the [`hash`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php)-method can be set to `TRUE`. This returns the result *directly* as binary data:

```
$hashPassword = hash('sha256', $password, $raw_output = true);
```